# Condition is right but it doesn't enter if statement

Tags: javascript

So, I am having this script where I am targeting user ranks on forum. It is very easy to get those values and it works. Now, when I reach the value "Guest", I try to make if statement to do something about it. Even tough the condition is 100% true, it doesn't enter inside it.

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var postDivs = $(".post");
    $.each(postDivs, function(index, div) {

        if ($(".post .postprofile-rank")[index].innerText == "Guest") {
            $(this).css("border-top", "15px solid #d4d4d4");
            return true;
        }

        var color = ($(".post .postprofile-info")[index].firstChild.nextSibling.data[0] == "#") ? $(".post .postprofile-info")[index].firstChild.nextSibling.data : "#d4d4d4";
        $(this).css("border-top", "15px solid " + color);
        var element1 = $(".post .postprofile-info ")[index].firstChild;
        $(".post .postprofile-info")[index].firstChild.nextSibling.data = "";
        element1.style.visibility = "hidden";

    });


});
```

Pay attention to:

```
if ($(".post .postprofile-rank")[index].innerText == "Guest") {
            $(this).css("border-top", "15px solid #d4d4d4");
            return true;
        }
```

$(".post .postprofile-rank")[index].innerText returns 100% value "Guest". It is a string. I checked like 100 times. But for some reason it just doesn't enter inside it. Why is this?

Comment: Did you exactly console log `$(".post .postprofile-rank")[index].innerText`? Did you check maybe it enters the condition but `$(this).css("border-top", "15px solid #d4d4d4");` this might not be doing anything ?

Comment: Add a console log above the if statement `console.log($(".post .postprofile-rank")[index].innerText)`. It could be that at the time of execution, the DOM is not in the state you think it is because some other process might populate this stuff later. Did you verify it is `Guest` by logging explicitly inside the code, and not trying to manually verify later in dev tools console or otherwise?

Comment: Maybe it goes in de if statement but continues the rest of code. I've juste read that to stop a `each` ind jQuery you need to `return false;` but you `return true;`

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for replies. I tried to console log before if statement and value is good. Value is guest before if but it skips if completely and try to execute code bellow and fails because guest posts don't have required field. Anyway, the problem remains the same. I even console log the statement and got false. How? String is Guest, I am comparing with string Guest and yet i get false.

Comment: @AleksandarArsic can you post a jsfiddle or runnable code snippet that we can run, edit, and fork so we can reproduce the issue with the HTML and make the fix? Thanks!

Comment: Okay guys, I solved this. There was eye invisible space in the string so I added trim() function. Silly mistake. Thanks everyone.